# How to use Accessors and Mutators in Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, setter, getter

I had a question about how to use accessors and mutators in javascript, because I've been taught to create getters and setters for every attribute of a class, like mentioned below:

```js
class card{
  constructor(aSuit, aColor, aNumber)
  {
    this.suit = aSuit;
    this.color = aColor;
    this.number = aNumber;
  }
  get suit(){
    return this._suit;
  }
  set suit(aSuit){
    this._suit= aSuit;
  }
  get color(aColor){
    return this._color;
  }
  set color(aColor){
    this._color= aColor;
  }
  get number(){
    return this._number;
  }
  set number(aNumber){
    this._number= aNumber;
  }
}

let card1 = new card("Spades", "red", 5);
console.log(card1.suit);
```

However, I found that it is not putting in the getters and setters still yielded the same result when I just used the following code instead.

```js
class card{
  constructor(aSuit, aColor, aNumber)
  {
    this.suit = aSuit;
    this.color = aColor;
    this.number = aNumber;
  }
}

let card1 = new card("Spades", "red", 5);
console.log(card1.suit);
```

I was just wondering what I was doing wrong.

I'm also confused about why in the accessors and mutators I was taught to name them as this._suit, rather than this.suit. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Using getters and setters just to access a `_`-prefixed property makes code *extremely* verbose for not much reason - like you're seeing, yes, it does give the same result. If you want to actually make info private, at least use a WeakMap instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah so does using the underscore make the attribute private? Is this because it has a slightly different variable name? Sorry I'm just a little bit confused

Comment: Not at all. It just gives the *indication* that it should only be accessed internally, which... isn't particularly useful. It's just an ordinary property name.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks I'll have a look at WeakMaps to see how they can be used for private variables

Comment: You may have been taught that, but it isn’t actually good advice. Happens sometimes.